# How to declare property type based on value of some other property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this:

```js
export type FieldType = 'number' | 'boolean' | 'string';

export interface IField {
  key: string;
  value: any;
  type: FieldType;
}
```

Is it possible to replace `values`'s `any` type withe some other definition so that values that are stored in `value` property are actually of type that `type` field contains. I.e. if an object has `'string'` value in `type` property, values that `value` property holds must be of type `string` (and so for `number` and `boolean` also).

So that this work this way:

```js
const booleanTypeError = <IField>{
  key: 'someKey',
  value: 'true', // throw error
  type: 'boolean'
};

const booleanTypeOK = <IField>{
  key: 'someKey',
  value: true, // no error
  type: 'boolean'
};

const stringTypeOK = <IField>{
  key: 'someKey',
  value: 'true', // no error
  type: 'string'
};

const stringTypeError = <IField>{
  key: 'someKey',
  value: true, // throw error
  type: 'string'
};
```

I tried to use `keyof` and `typeof`, but no luck as I was getting errors all the time. I'm using TypeScript 3.7.5 (but I can use 3.8 also).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use discriminated unions

```
type FieldType = 'number' | 'boolean' | 'string'

type IField = {
    key: string;
} & {
    value: number
    type: 'number'
} | {
    value: boolean
    type: 'boolean'
} | {
    value: string
    type: 'string'
}
```

With interfaces

```
interface Base {
  key: string
}

interface Bool extends Base {
  value: boolean
  type: 'boolean'
}

interface Num extends Base {
  value: number
  type: 'number'
}

interface Str extends Base {
  value: string
  type: 'string'
}

type IField = Bool | Num | Str
```

Comment: Hm, thanks, this might be working, but is it possible to have `interface IField` instead of `type IField `?